# addEventListener on a method of an object

Tags: javascript, cordova, memory-leaks, encapsulation, addeventlistener

I have a multi-"page" phonegap app and I'm trying to write the code properly, so I encapsulated the whole page 2 code in an object like below. but I observed that if I put `populateDB`, `errorCB` and `successCB` functions as methods of `page2_Obj`, saveData cannot find them. If I put those functions as members of saveData itself, everything works ok. so my qustions are: 
1. Why saveData cannot see its siblings?
2. Is it right to put those functions as members of saveData or there is a better way of doing this?
3. Am I leaking memory by putting those functions as members of saveData?

```
function page2_Obj() {
    this.bindEvents = function() {
        var obj = document.getElementById('savebtn');
        obj.addEventListener('click', this.saveData, false);

    this.unbindEvents = function() { /* blah */ }

    this.populateDB = function(tx) {
        /* blah */
    }

    this.errorCB = function(err) {
       alert("Error: "+err.code+ ' '+err.message);
    }

    this.successCB = function() {
       alert("success!");
    }

    this.saveData = function(){
        var db = window.openDatabase("Database", "1.0", "PhoneGap Demo", 200000);
        db.transaction(this.populateDB, this.errorCB, this.successCB);
    }
}
```

thanks

Comment: what is the purpose of using `this.` to each function?

Comment: I'm declaring functions with `this` so they become methods of page2_Obj and _trying_ to access them in saveData with `this`

Comment: You're passing the `save` method, but it doesn't keep reference to the `this` that was originally referencing it.

Comment: Right, but shouldn't `saveData` somehow be able to access it's siblings?

Answer (score 0):

To quickly answer your questions:
1. stop using THIS, your binding your methods to the GLOBAL object, bad idea.
2. I think you should look at the module pattern as a better way (end of my answer)
3. I don't think so.

I'm not sure what you are trying to do, though I believe your problem comes from the use of "this".

Are you using Page2_Obj as a constructor? (i.e. creating instances such as:

```
var pagex = new Page2_obj();
```

?
If not, you're binding all those inner methods to the GLOBAL object, bad idea. I also doubt this is what you want to do.

Could you explain what you are trying to achieve? If it's encapsulation, then an IIFE is better suited:

```
   var Page2_obj = (function() {
      // some private data
      var a = 'private string';

      // create some private methods
      function imPrivate() {
       // do something
      }

      // reveal public API (methods)
      return {
        imPrivate: imPrivate;
      };
    }());
```

Comment: Yes, as a constructor, when I load each page I run a function like `window[id] = new window[controller](); window[id].bindEvents();`. by encapsulation I'm trying to prevent cluttering my global object and so if two pages have two distinct functions named `errorCB`s the right one is called. How IIFE is going to help in this matter?